# How to WSGI application to make a redirect?

Tags: python, wsgi

interested in how to make a redirect in a simple WSGI app.
I try so:

```
def some_functions(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Location', 'http://some_page')])
    return []
```

But it doesn't work.
Must make a "return" without it not working, but that the return don't understand.
Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify a 3xx HTTP response code. For example, you can use `302 Found` to tell the client to visit the `Location` you provided.

Your code then becomes:

```
def some_functions(environ, start_response):
start_response('302 Found', [('Location', 'http://some_page')])
return []
```

You are right that you do need to return something. The `return []` line works fine here, since there isn't a request body to be returned. Normally, a WSGI app should return a list of bytes, and technically `[]` is just an empty list of bytes.

On that note, you also don't need to provide a `Content-Type`, since there is no content being returned. The only thing needed to be sent to the client is the redirect information.